# Show that$\,\,\int_{|f|\leq s}|f\,|^{q}\,d\mu\leq\frac{q}{q-p}s^{q-p}\lVert f\,\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^p\,\,,$ where $0<p<q<\infty$

Tags: proof-verification, weak-lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $s>0$

Let $f$ be a measurable function on $X$ .Show that $0<p<q<\infty $ we have
$$\int_{|f|\leq s}|f\,|^{q}\,d\mu\leq\frac{q}{q-p}s^{q-p}\lVert f\,\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^p$$

Here's my done :

If $\lVert f\,\rVert_{L^{p,\infty\,}}=\infty$ then there is nothing to prove.So assume $\lVert f\,\rVert_{L^{p,\infty\,}}<\infty$ Then we have

\begin{align}
\int_{|f|\leq s}|f\,|^{q}\,d\mu&=q\int_{0}^{s} \alpha^{q-1}\omega(\alpha)\,d\alpha\\
&\leq q\int_{0}^{s} \alpha^{q-1-p}\lVert f\,\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^p\,\,\,d\alpha\\
&=\frac{q}{q-p}s|_{0}^{q-p}\lVert f\,\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^p\\
&=\frac{q}{q-p}s^{q-p}\lVert f\,\rVert_{L^{p,\infty}}^p
\end{align}

where $\omega(\alpha)$ is the distribution function of $f$.

If you have the time,please check my proof for validity with me. Any advice would appreciate.Thanks for considering my request.

$\rule{18cm}{2pt}$

I take note below this line that anyone can ignore it or give your valuable suggestion.

\begin{align}
\int_{|f|\leq s}|f(x)|^{q}\,d\mu(x)&= q\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{q-1}\chi_{\{\alpha\,:\, 0<\alpha\leq s\}}\omega(\alpha)\,d\alpha\\
&=q\int_{0}^{s}\alpha^{q-1}\chi_{\{\alpha\,:\, 0<\alpha\leq s\}}\omega(\alpha)\,d\alpha \,+ q\int_{s}^{\infty}\alpha^{q-1}\chi_{\{\alpha\,:\, 0<\alpha\leq s\}}\omega(\alpha)\,d\alpha\\
&=q\int_{0}^{s}\alpha^{q-1}\chi_{\{\alpha\,:\, 0<\alpha\leq s\}}\omega(\alpha)\,d\alpha \,+ 0\\
&=q\int_{0}^{s}\alpha^{q-1}\omega(\alpha)\,d\alpha
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, or if we let $E=\{x\in X: |f(x)|\leq s\}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\int_{|f|\leq s}|f|^{q}d\mu&=\int_{E}|f|^{q}d\mu\\
&=q\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{q-1}\omega_{E}(\alpha)d\alpha\\
&=q\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha^{q-1}\chi_{0\leq\alpha<s}\omega_{E}(\alpha)d\alpha\\
&=q\int_{0}^{s}\alpha^{q-1}\omega(\alpha)d\alpha,
\end{align*}
where $\omega_{E}(\alpha)=\{x\in E:|f(x)|>\alpha\}$, if $\alpha\geq s$, then $\omega_{E}(\alpha)=0$, if $\alpha<s$, then $\omega_{E}(\alpha)=\omega(\alpha)$.